# Fetch Latitude & Longitude from Google Place Autocomplete and Directions script

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

Does anyone know how to fetch latitude and longitude from within this google Place Autocomplete and Directions script?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions

I'd like to pass the latitude and longitude value to a hidden field like below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude"  />
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude"  />
```

Comment: Which latitude and longitude are you trying to get?  How are you trying to get it that hasn't worked? There will be one for the origin and one for the destination.  (Do you just want the last one selected?)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that: it's from the ORIGIN solely.
I've tried many solution as seen on this forum but none seem to fit in with Place Autocomplete and Direction script...

Comment: I tried many variation of this script here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478646/google-map-api-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-autocomplete-without-map/42075105#42075105[/link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the `{placeIdOnly: true}` from the [`AutocompleteOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions).  With that set the `place` object only includes the `name` and `placeId` of the place.
2. get the latitude and longitude from the `place` object like this:

```
  document.getElementById("latitude").value= place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById("longitude").value= place.geometry.location.lng();
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1m6rg401/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });

  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
  var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
  var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    originInput /*, {placeIdOnly: true} */ );
  var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    destinationInput /*, {placeIdOnly: true} */ );

  this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
}

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
  var me = this;
  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    me.travelMode = mode;
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
      return;
    }
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      document.getElementById("orig_latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
      document.getElementById("orig_longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
    } else {
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
      document.getElementById("dest_latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
      document.getElementById("dest_longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
    }
    me.route();
  });

};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
    return;
  }
  var me = this;

  this.directionsService.route({
    origin: {
      'placeId': this.originPlaceId
    },
    destination: {
      'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId
    },
    travelMode: this.travelMode
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
};
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#origin-input,
#destination-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
}
#origin-input:focus,
#destination-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
#mode-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#mode-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="orig_latitude" name="orig_latitude" />
<input type="text" id="orig_longitude" name="orig_longitude" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="dest_latitude" name="dest_latitude" />
<input type="text" id="dest_longitude" name="dest_longitude" />

<input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter an origin location">

<input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a destination location">

<div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
  <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
  <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
  <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
```