# Get Latitude and Longitude from Google Places Autocomplete in React Native

Tags: react-native, google-maps-api-3

I've implemented autocomplete for my address field, but the json returned from the Google Maps Places Autocomplete doesn't include the geocoded coords for the places.

There are some answers out there that don't seem to fit. For instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478646/google-map-api-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-autocomplete-without-map) one refers to things like `google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);` which I don't think is a thing in React Native.

Other answers appear to be based on `react-native-google-places-autocomplete`, but I've implemented this myself and I'd love to not do it again using that module.

Here's my method where I call the API.

```js
  async handleAddressChange() {
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=${GoogleAPIKey}&input=${this.state.address}`;
    try {
      const result = await fetch(url);
      const json = await result.json();
      this.setState({ addressPredictions: json.predictions });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  setAddress(prediction) { 
    this.setState({ address: prediction.description, showPredictions: false });
  }
```

The API response doesn't have any `place` or `geometry` property on it:

```
Object {
  "description": "1234 Some Avenue Northeast, Washington, DC, USA",
  "id": "4c79fba1b3a5ad33478b79b54896a75a4d56ca53",
  "matched_substrings": Array [
    Object {
      "length": 4,
      "offset": 0,
    },
  ],
  "place_id": "ChIJneQ1fBO5t4kRf8mTw4ieb4Q",
  "reference": "ChIJneQ1fBO5t4kRf8mTw4ieb4Q",
  "structured_formatting": Object {
    "main_text": "1234 Some Avenue Northeast",
    "main_text_matched_substrings": Array [
      Object {
        "length": 4,
        "offset": 0,
      },
    ],
    "secondary_text": "Washington, DC, USA",
  },
  "terms": Array [
    Object {
      "offset": 0,
      "value": "1600",
    },
    Object {
      "offset": 5,
      "value": "Maryland Avenue Northeast",
    },
    Object {
      "offset": 32,
      "value": "Washington",
    },
    Object {
      "offset": 44,
      "value": "DC",
    },
    Object {
      "offset": 48,
      "value": "USA",
    },
  ],
  "types": Array [
    "street_address",
    "geocode",
  ],
}
```

Comment: There should be other properties in the response besides the predictions, which amount only for the suggestions prior to the user actually selecting one of them

Comment: With this data, make a [Place Details Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceDetailsRequest) to the Places API with the `place_id` returned, which is `ChIJneQ1fBO5t4kRf8mTw4ieb4Q` in your above example.

Comment: @MrUpsidown this does appear to be the best way. Happy to mark it **the** answer if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Here you are! See below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the place id (`ChIJneQ1fBO5t4kRf8mTw4ieb4Q` for the example in your question), you can do a place details request.

Make sure you include the Places library in your API call: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places` and a valid API key.

```js
function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 15
    });

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: 'ChIJneQ1fBO5t4kRf8mTw4ieb4Q'
    }, function(place, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            // Create marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            // Center map on place location
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        }
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

Comment: "Places detail request" is the right way to go. However, this answer appears to be for a web application rather than React Native, and uses `google.maps` which I'm fairly sure RN doesn't have access too. Still, making a places detail request with a simple fetch works in my situation.

Comment: Yes, this is for a JS app, but you get the idea. You can make the same request to the [web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details).

Comment: From a cost perspective wont this be making an extra API call?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a solution I found:

```js
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{ fields: "geometry" }}
  fetchDetails={true} // you need this to fetch the details object onPress
  placeholder="Search"
  query={{
    key: "API_KEY_GOES_HERE",
    language: "en", // language of the results
  }}
  onPress={(data, details = null) => {
    console.log("data", data);
    console.log("details", details);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(details?.geometry?.location));
  }}
  onFail={(error) => console.error(error)}
/>
```

Comment: worked like charm

Comment: thank you!! Finally something that worked!